# Is there any code-based tool for building RPAs?

Tags: rpa

We have developed some RPA processes using Workfusion but we don't feel confortable about using an IDE with boxes to specify the steps

Is there any code-based platform or tool to develop these processes? Are there some specific node or python libraries in order to develop RPAs (windows management, file management, screen management, mouse management, etc)

We have looked RobotJS but it seems pretty quiet lately.

Answer (score 1):

I would try UltimateRPA. Its code based and you can easily combine the commands for robot with python code

Answer (score 1):

[ThinkAutomation](https://www.thinkautomation.com/) is a great RPA tool. You can called Javascript, VBScript or PowerShell directly or compile your own exe in any other language and call it from the app with cmd line arguments.